# PHP Keep drop down value after submitting from database

Tags: php, html, sql, onchange

I want to keep my drop-down value after on change submit.

**HTML code**

```
<select id="Doctor" name="Doctor" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                    <?php
                    $Store->displayDoctors()
                    ?>
</select>
```

PHP Code

```
public function displayDoctors(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM doctor";
        $result = @mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $data['docID'] ."'>" .$data['FirstName']." ".$data['LastName'] ."</option>";  
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use like:
HTML:

```
<select id="Doctor" name="Doctor" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                    <?php
                    $Store->displayDoctors($_REQUEST['Doctor'])
                    ?>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
public function displayDoctors($value=false){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM doctor";
        $result = @mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $selected="";
            if($data['docID']==$value)
            {
              $selected="selected";
            }
            echo "<option value='". $data['docID'] ."' $selected>" .$data['FirstName']." ".$data['LastName'] ."</option>";  
        }     
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help again. The code is working perfectly. Just a quick question what is $value=false mean? i don't understand that part.

Comment: we are passing argument to function, initially there is no value so we are passing false.

Comment: so it will only be false if the argument is empty ?

Comment: @yukang yes right